# Firebase Cloud functions - collapsible IOS notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I use cloud functions to send notifications. It works, but I want collapsible messages. How can I do it? Here is my current function:

```
exports.sendNotifications = functions.database
    .ref("/users/{userId}/data")
    .onWrite(event => {
        const userId = event.params.userId;

        if (!event.data.val()) {
            return;
        }

    const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: `Hey`,
          body: 'It's your turn!'
          //icon: receiver.photoURL
        }
      };

const options = {
    collapseKey: 'myturnkey'
  };

    return admin
        .database()
        .ref(`users\/${userId}\/data\/notificationkey`)
        .once('value')
        .then(data => {
            console.log('inside key', data.val());
          if (data.val()) {
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(data.val(), payload, options);
          }
        });     
    });
```

I tried "collapseKey" and "collapse_key" in options but none of them works, I still receive notifications every time my function is called, so I get a list of notifications on my iphone whereas I want only one.

EDIT

I also tried the parameter "apns-collapse-id" according to the [FCM messages documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options), but when when I try to deploy the functions the console says " apns-collapse-id: 'myturnkey', ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token -"

Thank you,

Alexandre

Comment: I think `thread-id` is the key you are looking for; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1

Comment: It seems to be what I would need if the logic was in my app. With firebase cloud functions the good parameter seems to be collapseKey on Android,
apns-collapse-id on iOS, and collapse_key in legacy protocols (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages ). But as said in my post and in my other comment I don't manage to make it work... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, or manipulate current notifications in other ways, using the `registration.getNotifications()` API which gives you access to all the currently visible notifications for your web app.

> But you need to write this code in your `Service-worker`

see [this documention for merging-notifications](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/04-common-notification-patterns/#merging-notifications)

Comment: It seems that I can do it in my firebase cloud function : go to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages and look for "apns-collapse-id" . I tried this parameter as well but when when I try to deploy the functions the console says " apns-collapse-id: 'myturnkey',
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -"